# MariaDB concatenate 2 tables with same number of rows

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

Say I have 2 tables with exactly SAME number of rows, but no other obvious relations:

tableA

| ID | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | orange |

tableB

| itemID | volume |
| --- | --- |
| 5550 | 50 |
| 5551 | 70 |

Can I join these 2 tables horizontally, to form 1 table like the following?

| ID | items | itemID | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | 5550 | 50 |
| 2 | orange | 5551 | 70 |

Comment: on what basis are you joining these tables ? Is it mysql, which version()

Comment: based on they definitely have same number of rows, but no other basis

Comment: '10.6.3-MariaDB'

Comment: you can try rank() or row_number. Generate row_num for both table and then join as the relationship is missing.

Comment: @AmitVerma could you provide an answer please?

Comment: SQL table have no inherent order so you cannot place "the first" row of one table near "the first" row of another table. You have to provide ordering criteria for both datasets to align them vertically. The correct way is to have relationship between them via Foreign Keys, but according to the current structure the data looks like it has no relation or is already broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
create table TableA(ID INT, Items varchar(20));
create table TableB(ItemId INT, volume varchar(20));

insert into TableA(Id, items) values (1, 'banana'), (2, 'orange');
insert into TableB(ItemId, volume) values (5550, '50'), (5551, '70');

SELECT A.ID, A.Items, B.ItemId, B.volume
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, Items, rownum()R
   FROM TableA
)A INNER join
(
  SELECT ItemId,volume,rownum()R
  FROM TableB
)B ON A.R=B.R
```

Comment: This looks good but how can I allocate the SELECTed value to tableA? i.e. make tableA to be the new values?

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 tables with exactly SAME number of rows, but no other obvious relations and on both tables , respectively ID and itemID defines the uniqueness of the rows you can apply  [MySQL ROW_NUMBER Function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) and join on the row_number, the order by clause is important.

Try:

```
SELECT tbla.ID, tbla.Items, tblb.ItemId, tblb.volume
FROM (
       SELECT ID, Items, row_number() over( order by ID desc )row_numA
       FROM TableA
     )tbla      
INNER join
     (  SELECT ItemId,volume,row_number() over(order by ItemId desc)row_numB
        FROM TableB
     ) tblb ON tbla.row_numA=tblb.row_numB
order by tbla.ID asc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=15d13d29a84a55c4d029115c87eebe8f